# window.location not firing after ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm not sure if this is related to an ajax call or not.  I'm very new to Ajax, and so I suspect it is the cause.

I run the following javascript:

```
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
"use strict";
var objXMLHttp = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    objXMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    objXMLHttp = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

return objXMLHttp;
}

function delete_director(i) {
"use strict";
var r, url;

r = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to disable this director");
url = "ajax.php?task=director&event=delete&UserId=" + i;

if (r === true) {
    mdata = new GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (mdata === null) {
        alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }

    mdata.open("GET", url, true);
    mdata.send(null);
}
}
```

And that calls into the following php function:

```
function deletedirector()
{
    $UserId=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['UserId']);
    $query = "update tbl_users set IsDisabled='1' where UserId=".$UserId;
    $result = mysql_query($query) OR die('Cannot perform query!');
    if ($result) {
        error_log("a");
        ?><script type="text/javascript">window.location='index.php?task=director&success=Director Successfully Deleted.'</script><?
    } else {
        error_log("b");
        ?><script type="text/javascript">window.location='index.php?task=director&error=Director Deletion Failed.'</script><?
    }
}
```

The db shows that the director was deleted, and "a" prints in the error log, but the window.location never fires.

The user experience is that the browser prompts for confirmation, and after that - nothing.  A javascript console shows now error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already return new object (of XMLHttpRequest API) with function, so you don't need **new** here

```
...
if (r === true) {
    mdata = GetXmlHttpObject();
...
```

and try to use [onreadystatechange](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) like this

```
mdata.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (mdata.readyState === 4) {
        alert("some text");
    } else {
        alert(mdata.status);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Givi.  This popped up three alert boxes: "200", "some text", "some text".  I'm guessing that it got back an HTTP 200 from the php function, then the state changed two more times after that where the state was != 4.  But I'm not sure how to act on this information.

Comment: Rather than having the php function do a window.location, I had the onreadystatechange do a location.reload and that made it work.  Thank you.